# How do I display the correct character from UTF-8 string in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have the original text: `ferhat gÃ¶Ã§er` and I want to display it like `ferhat göçer`. I have tried a lot of things but none of them work.

All pages have the following header and meta:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I've tried with `iconv`, `utf8_deconde` and all other bunch of functions and still no luck.

How should I display the correct symbol for these weird characters? I have this data in the database.

Comment: Probably the problem is in your database: Is the encoding in your database set as utf-8?

Comment: First of all load the page in your browser, then check what your browser thinks the encoding is. Post this as an addendum to your question.

Comment: `ferhat gÃ¶Ã§er` is what you get if you convert utf-8 encoded `ferhat göçer` from latin-1 to utf-8. Probably at some point it was incorrectly assumed that the text was latin-1 encoded. Then `iconv -f UTF-8 -t LATIN1` would give you the correct utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_decode` would normally do what you want, as the contents of your string is something which has been UTF-8–encoded twice:

```
var_dump(utf8_decode('ferhat gÃ¶Ã§er'));
```

([see example](http://codepad.org/daGdU6a7).) However, this assumes the following:

1. That your files are saved in UTF-8 format.
2. That your headers are being served correctly. (Check the HTML / HTTP headers in a browser.)
3. That your PHP internal encoding / default charset is set to UTF-8.

Also, bear in mind that before any INSERTs/UPDATEs to the database, the following will prevent the issue from re-occurring:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be also server-related. Some providers have their apache2 configured to force ISO-XXXX encoding regardless of what you set via PHP or in the `<header>` of the page.

edit: You can verify this by inspecting the actual headers the pageload gives you. Either with browser tools such as Inspect -> Network panel in Chrome, Firebug or a website such as http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php